# Ошибка программы

Tags: c++

Такие ошибки:

> prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
>
> prog.cpp:20:32: error: ‘strcpy_s’ was not declared in this scope
>     strcpy_s(pStr1, strSize1, str1);
>   prog.cpp:38:37: error: ‘strcat_s’ was not declared in this scope strcat_s(pStr1, requiredSize, pStr2);
>   prog.cpp: In function ‘char* giveNewMem(char*, int)’:
>   prog.cpp:51:36: error: ‘strcpy_s’ was not declared in this scope
>     strcpy_s(strInFunc, reqSize, pstr1);

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

char* giveNewMem(char *pstr1, int reqSize);

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    char* str1;
    char* str2;
    cout << "Enter first string:";
    cin >> str1;
    cout << "Enter second string:";
    cin >> str2;
    int strSize1 = strlen(str1) + 1;
    int strSize2 = strlen(str2) + 1;

    char* pStr1 = new char[strSize1];
    strcpy_s(pStr1, strSize1, str1);

    char* pStr2 = new char[strSize2];
    strcpy_s(pStr2, strSize2, str2);

    cout << "1)" << pStr1 << endl;
    cout << "2)" << pStr2 << endl << endl;

    cout << "pStr1 занимает " << strSize1 << " байт памяти c \\0" << endl;
    cout << "pStr2 занимает " << strSize2 << " байт памяти c \\0" << endl;

    int requiredSize = (strSize1 + strSize2) - 1;
    cout << "\nНеобходимо " << requiredSize << " байт памяти для объединения строк." << endl << endl;

    pStr1 = giveNewMem(pStr1, requiredSize); //функция, которая перевыделит память

    strcat_s(pStr1, requiredSize, pStr2);
    cout << "pStr1: " << pStr1 << endl << endl;

    delete[] pStr1; // освобождаем память, которая была перевыделена в функции для strInFunc 
    delete[] pStr2; // освобождаем память, которая была выделена в main 

    return 0;
}

char* giveNewMem(char *pstr1, int reqSize)
{
    char* strInFunc = new char[reqSize]; // для копирования строки pstr1 перед удалением памяти

    strcpy_s(strInFunc, reqSize, pstr1);

    delete [] pstr1; // освобождаем память pstr1

    return strInFunc;
}
```

Comment: А что у вас за компилятор? Он вообще эти расширения - `_s` - поддерживает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, вы работаете с GCC, но в нем эти функции не поддерживаются.

См., например, https://stackoverflow.com/a/40046076/9123401

Answer (score 1):

strcpy_s - это не стандартная функция для языка С++, а расширение для компилятора Visual Studio. Такая функция есть в языке С (стандарт С11), но не в С++.

Comment: И почему не использовать std::string?

Comment: Наверное нужно  уметь работать и  с Си строками и указательями, по этому поводу можно специально не прибегнуть к С++

Answer (score 1):

```
char* str1;  //  и что?
char* str2;
cout << "Enter first string:";
cin >> str1; // вы серьезно?
cout << "Enter second string:";
cin >> str2;
```

У вас указатели ничем не инициализированы, не выделена область памяти под указатели... Что и куда вы вводите?...

сделайте например так:

```
char* str1;
istream_iterator<string> is(cin);
const size_t sz = is->size(); // размер строки
str1 = const_cast<char*>(is->c_str());
```

Comment: Только к ошибке компиляции "was not declared in this scope" это имеет никакое отношение

Comment: А это логическая ошибка, и нормальный компилятор должен вывести предупреждение, и логическая ошибка хуже ошибки компиляции. А с ошибкой компиляции  вы уже получили ответы

Comment: мне нужно в зависимости от длины введенной строки выделить соответсвующую память для указателей

Answer (score -1):

`#include <string.h>` нужно

Чтение документации, как это не странно, помогает. Тут вот https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/td1esda9.aspx написано какой заголовок подключать.

Comment: `#include <cstring>
using namespace std;` - у автора вопроса это есть.

Comment: @Mikhailo с каких пор имена инклюдов странным образом модифицируются перед включением?

Comment: Стандартные заголовки С++. Вы этого не знали?